# accessing a docker container's file system through terminal

Tags: docker

So I have successfully downloaded and got running the dockerfile/nginx image from the registry. How can I now access its file system by firing up a bash terminal on it?

Maybe I am missing something conceptually here. Do I need to ssh into it? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/docker-exploring-containers-file-system

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can start an interactive shell in a new image:

```
sudo docker run -i -t nginx /bin/bash
```

This gives you access to the container and you can change things. When done you need to save your changes in a new reusable image:

```
sudo docker commit <container_id> <some_name>
```

This approach makes sense for testing. Usually you would use [Dockerfiles](http://docs.docker.io/reference/builder/) to automate this.

In case your image has a default entry point you can overwrite it:

```
docker run -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash nginx
```

Comment: thanks, I get 'invalid option /bin/bash' so I am guessing that the creators of the image have disabled or removed bash?

Comment: How do I save my changes into a new reusable image without first exiting the running container?

Comment: open a new terminal and use `sudo docker commit <container_id> <some_name>`

Comment: Some images have both an ENTRYPOINT and CMD, try `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash nginx -i`