# how to install an app inside of running docker container?

Tags: docker, bitcoin, nano

I am testing some Bitcoin related code and in order to test it have installed bitcoin-testnet-box within a docker container.

I use this guide:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box/

I pulled and run the docker without any problems.

BUT, I can not edit the bitcoin.conf files in their directories because I dont have an editor like NANO installed.

I would like to do:

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

But it's not working. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own Dockerfile to build on freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

Dockerfile

```
FROM freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box
MAINTAINER dude
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nano
```

In the directory with your Dockerfile run:

```
docker build -t "mybitcoinimage" .
```

and start the container

```
docker run -it mybitcoinimage /bin/bash
```

And you are in with root access and nano.

Comment: thanks, finally it worked, I created a file named "Dockerfile" as you recommended with those credentials. But building was only working by this command:      **docker build - < Dockerfile**   . And then with command:     **docker images** I found the new volume. And I started it with: **docker run -it 7a0a14be2634** And the editor nano works perfect as well.

Comment: @user3335302 please accept the answer as a courtsey to people helping you.

Answer (score 2):

It is best if you add the apt-get command to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box/blob/master/Dockerfile) and re-create the container. There are already `RUN` commands in there to show you how to do it.

You can also use docker run to execute a command. This could be apt-get. Besides, to inspect a running container, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/docker-exploring-containers-file-system).

Comment: I dont know how to do that...

I run it by:

docker run -t -i freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

do you mean I should run it by:

docker run -t -i freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box apt-get install nano ?.. Because then i also get error

Answer (score -3):

Also for those of you who are interested:

I was only able to connect to the bitcoind from outside by running the docker with this command:

```
docker run -p 19001:19001 -it 7a0a14be2634 //7a.. is the volume))
```

then I can do a telnet to check if I can make a connection to bitcoind from another VM

```
telnet 192.168.142.163 19001
```

*Now it finally works perfectly*