# Docker: Unable to execute RUN command after ADD when starting from scratch

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a custom Linux Alpine docker for ARM architecture starting from the "scratch" image. I don't understand why I can't execute any RUN command after I execute ADD. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD rootfs.tar /

MAINTAINER Vittorio_Cozzolino

RUN apk add nodejs
```

And this is the output that I get when the automated build completes (the last line contains the error):

```
Client:  Version:      1.8.1  API version:  1.20  Go version:  
go1.4.2  Git commit:   d12ea79  Built:        Thu Aug 13 02:49:29 UTC
2015  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:  Version:      1.8.3-rc1  API version:  1.20  Go version:  
go1.4.2  Git commit:   6f21aba  Built:        Mon Sep 28 20:03:03 UTC
2015  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64 Step 0 : FROM scratch
 ---> Step 1 : ADD rootfs.tar /
 ---> dd771ffd56ea702 Step 2 : MAINTAINER Vittorio_Cozzolino
 ---> 825fc4c990c8a33 Step 3 : RUN apk add nodejs [91mexec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
```

Actually `/bin/sh` exists and, in fact, if I run `CMD ["/bin/sh"]` I don't get any error. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: try to do first `apk update` and then it should be OK

Comment: @user2915097 Just tried, nothing changed. I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMD ["/bin/sh"]` is a simple declaration of the default command to run, so it will always work.

Check if the tar is indeed unpacked, as there was a [similar issue in 9541](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9541): limit your Dockerfile to the `ADD` directive, and [use `docker exec` or a simple `ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22730520/6309) to see what is in there (and with which owner/permission).
If the Dockerfile complains about a missing `/bin/sh`, and `/bin/sh` is in the tar archive... chances are that archive didn't uncompress properly.