# No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, build, tfs-2015

I am in the process of upgrading our existing solution to .Net 4.6.1 and have been unable to get our unit tests to run during a server build. Locally they run as expected and flipping the framework version back to .Net 4.5.1 makes them run again on the server.

I am getting the following error:

> No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I have reproduced the problem in a simpler setup:

- Solution with a single C# Unit Test project with two tests (one failing, one passing).
- XAML build definition
  using the Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml)
- TFS 2015 Update 1
  XAML build server with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1
  installed (have six similar servers and all produce the same result)

Comment: According to Brian Harry from Microsoft, this is bug they are currently investigating. It should be fixed in Update 2, and a temporary workaround should be posted later. Source: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/11/30/vs-2015-update-1-and-tfs-2015-update-1-are-available.aspx#10665420)

Comment: I have the same problem for .Net 3.5 SP1 in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Comment: @AndreyBushman: The error might be in 2013U5 too as it was released together with 2015RTM. But the workaround should work in your case too.

Comment: I had a similar problem, the workaround was simply in vs, under the test settings, to select the right default processer (32/64) bit, and no keep the engine runnig. (vs 2017.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for .Net 4.6 now.

> Unable to run .Net 4.6.x unit tests as part of a XAML TFS Build with TFS 2015 UPdate1
>   **Source:**https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2245723

Here is a similar question for you reference: [Unable to run .Net 4.6 Unit tests of TFS 2015 XAML build server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee5818eb-e994-4010-8a7b-6eda0e7f8338/unable-to-run-net-46-unit-tests-of-tfs-2015-xaml-build-server?forum=vsunittest)

Comment: Hi Patrick. Both of the links you supply is cases opened by me, so I wouldn't trust them as reference ;-).

Answer (score 80):

You can try to change your **default processor architecture** in your Test Setting from X86 to X64. In my case this was the problem.

This happens if the platform target of your project under test is set to `x64`.

[image: Screenshot of test settings]

Comment: This solved it for me. In my case, both the project being tested and the test project were set to x86. Tests were disoverable but failed to run. After I changed it to Any CPU, tests ran.

Comment: I just had the same problem and this resolved it.  I am also quite suspicious that this may have had a bad nego-synergistic effect on my main project references, which suddenly stopped loading a particular DLL, but have not conclusively determined this nasty side effect.

Comment: Worked for me too, except that the menu was Test -> Processor Architecture for AnyCPU projects then select X64

Answer (score 73):

My build was not finding the tests either.  My setup and solution for finding the tests are as follows.

I use VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) and have a build that is configured to refresh the NUGET packages on every build.  I am using NUnit and found that running the following NUGET command (from the package manager console in Visual Studio) to add NUnitTestAdapter library to my test project and the checking in the packages.config made the tests run in my VSTS build.

```
Install-Package NUnitTestAdapter
```

As Maurice mentions in the Comment to this post for NUnit3 use the following [NUGET package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/) (Look for other utils on the link. i.e: dotnet CLI and Paket CLI)

```
Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm also currently using VSTS. As adviced I added NUnit3TestAdapter (since I'm using NUnit 3.8.1) and this solution solved my problem. Thank you :-)

Comment: Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter solved my issue :)

Answer (score 56):

In my case, I had to:

1. Convert test project to netcore 2.0 (was netstandard 2.0)
2. Add nuget package `xunit.runner.visualstudio`

Reference:
[http://www.neekgreen.com/2017/11/20/xunit-no-test-is-available/](http://web.archive.org/web/20180331085013/http://www.neekgreen.com/2017/11/20/xunit-no-test-is-available/)

Comment: same issue was with me. I am using xunit with .net core

Comment: This also worked for me in Visual Studio 2017 with xunit and .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: in my case was a .net 4.6.1 project so the only thing missing was the xunit runner. Installed it and worked.

Comment: Same as Juan. Only the runner package was missing. Running this in the package manager for the test project solved it:

install-package xunit.runner.visualstudio

Comment: Confirmed. Accidentally removed the runner.visualstudio nuget package (keeping the xunit one). Re-introducing it fixed this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I'm using MSTest. For me, it was **version missmatch and missing another dependent package**-

1) My package folder contains only MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.1 package. In my project file(.csproj) the reference in Target Name was MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0 package which was not present in package folder. My packages.config has also reference of MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0 .

2) So I installed MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0 from nuget package manager and align MSTest.TestFramework version to 1.2.0 in project and package file. Finally I add Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions in the reference.

Then everything was OK. Hope this help someone.

Comment: I bumped into this with .Net 4.6.1 VS2017. I ended up rolling back to 1.2.0 - definitely make sure you dont have two different versions in your packages folder or in source control.

Comment: Mine appeared to find the tests, but yes, missing "MSTest.TestAdapter" was the real issue. No nice errors or warning (VS2017 15.8). All looked good except no tests were found, despite appearing in the test explorer..... So when I did "install-package MSTest.TestAdapter" suddenly my tests ran as expected. Thanks MS - 3 hours wasted...........

Comment: Installing the MSTest.TestAdapter 1.4.0 did it for me in VS 2019. I only wasted 30 minutes thanks to you.

Answer (score 11):

I got this error and was able to resolve it.

1. I use Visual Studio Professional 2017
2. In VS, I navigated to Tools --> Extensions And Updates
3. At the top of the menu, I'd noticed that my NUnit adapter was disabled
4. I clicked the [Enable] button
5. I was able to initiate tests without errors.

Comment: Yes! And don't forget to restart Visual Studio. That was required for me.

Comment: "At the top of the menu" what does that mean?

Comment: @SaiyajinGohan. After you complete step 2, the "Extensions and Updates" window appears. At the top of this window, I saw the NUnit adapter was disabled. Hope this clarifies....

Comment: Thanks for that, I still couldn't get this working with the project I was working on. Luckily it was a test project and the next one worked. Still a mystery as to why.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling all testing related NuGet packages for the project:
`Xunit`, `Xunit.runner.vistualstudio`, `Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk`

Comment: To add for others: yes, the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package is needed to run Xunit tests with `dotnet test`, despite the name.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install Nunit and NUnitTestAdapter latest version from NUGET package.
2. Go to -> Test -> Test Settings -> Default processor architecture -> Change to X64
3. Build the solution.
4. This will resolve Run Test and Debugger issue in unit testing and it will start working.

Comment: This actually worked for me after banging my head in so many directions and suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

This problem surfaces for Visual Studio 2017 again.
Most likely another bug but the same outcome.

One workaround that seems to work is to uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger from the affected machine.

Answer (score 6):

I'll throw my solution onto the heap. In my case, I am adding a couple of projects to an existing solution along with Test projects for them. We're using MSTest. There was a previous UnitTest.testsettings file enabled on the solution that was causing compatibility issues.

Clicking on the settings file removed the check and the test run was successful for my tests.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem in VSTS with .Net 4.6.2.  If you are seeing this from your VSTS console output, the workaround provided by @Sushil still works in VSTS and is needed.  Unfortunately the "Test Assemblies" task provided by Microsoft passes, so you really don't even know there is a problem unless you check the output and find none of your tests actually executed!

[image: VSTS Test Fix]

Comment: My problem was with (on-prem) TFS 2015 Update 1 and it was fixed with Update 2. I am not sure if the same issue exist/existed with VSTS.

Answer (score 5):

With net6.0 targetFramework I added these packages to .csproj-file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.5" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.5" />
```

after which it started working. earlier versions may not be compatible with net6.0.

Do check the latest versions for the packages appropiate for your .NET version for example from nuget.org

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar issue when tried nUnit in VS 2017 and it's not a core project.
Installing `NUnit3TestAdapter` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running your tests inside docker using multistage building and tests aren't found. 
Make sure you copy all files not only project files like below Dockerfile section.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MainProject/FirstApp.csproj", "MainProject/"]
COPY ["TestProject/*", "TestProject/"]

RUN dotnet restore "TestProject/TestProject.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "TestProject/TestProject.csproj" -c Release
RUN dotnet test "TestProject/TestProject.csproj" -c Release
```

Comment: This did indeed bite me.  I think the clue that this is happening is that it FINDS the unit test DLL, but it does NOT find any tests in it.  I also found that putting this inline after your copy statements will let you inspect to see what WAS copied (here /app/tests is your target directory on the Docker image):   RUN file="$(ls -al /app/tests)" && echo $file  (see [this post for more info on echo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215313/97803) )

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by installing **NUnit3TestAdapter** NuGet into my project (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/).

```
dotnet add package NUnit3TestAdapter --version 3.17.0
```

My **.csproj** file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is obviously being found by people with a range of scenarios, my answer will cover running **XUnit** tests on a **.NET Core** project using build pipeline on **Azure DevOps** but may help others too.

- Ensure you have the XUnit test adapters installed from nuget as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517104/4051181).
- In the yaml for your build pipeline, add `otherConsoleOptions: '/framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'` to the `inputs` of your `VSTest@2` step (with the version number set to whatever version of .NET Core you are using). See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019#general-command-line-options) for more info.
- While this is not mandatory, I would recommend also adding `failOnMinTestsNotRun: true` so that the build pipeline will report a failure if zero tests are run.
- If you run a build at this point, you may find that your tests run but the pipeline then gives the error `The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found`. You can solve this by changing your filter from the default `**\*test*.dll`to `**\*test.dll` (note the removed asterisk), or some other pattern which will match your test project's DLL. The reason for this is that XUnit places a file called `testhost.dll` in the output directory, as explained in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569#issuecomment-550199854).

If you are using the older pipelines which do not use yaml, the same options should be available. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836517/4051181) covers adding the framework, I assume there will also be an option to "Fail the task if a minimum number of tests are not run" or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

I installed `nunit3adapter` package and it worked for me from my test log:
`-->(NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 6 of 6 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run)`

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by issue in VS 2017 & 4.6.2 test project with the following steps:

1. Remove references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll and extensions
2. Install the
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated nuget
   package

Answer (score 3):

Using .Net Core with a build pipeline in TFS 2017, my Visual Studio Test step was passing without actually executing any tests. Had to edit the step, "Advanced Execution Options" -> "Other console options" to include:

```
/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0"
```

(That field also contains `/platform:x64`)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you've got the "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" nuget installed.

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen for async tests if you have the wrong return type. The return type should be Task, and not void.

Answer (score 2):

I use MSTest.

I installed from Nuget the latest version of MSTest.TestFramework and replaced OOB Remove references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Then Installed from neget the latest version of Microsoft.TestPlatform

It allowed me to run test with a command:

```
".\packages\Microsoft.TestPlatform.16.6.1\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" "UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll" /logger:trx
```

But I got the same error.
The root cause of the error that I didn't specify a test adapter which parses the assembly and finds tests.

Solution:

1. Install a nuget package "MSTest.TestAdapter"
2. Specify a test adapter in the end of a command:

   /TestAdapterPath:".\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build_common"

Comment: Updating MSTest.TestAdapter (2.1.2->2.2.7) and MSTest.TestFramework (2.1.2->2.2.7) fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have just been through this issue. It seems there may be a lot of causes for it.
In my case, I was trying some codes and due to that, I renamed the project, removed it.. added it again... and all of a sudden, my single test stopped working and the Test output window was showing this error:
"No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again"
The Debug output was showing errors related to the platform:
"Following dll(s) do not match current settings, which are .netframework , version 4.5 and platform X86."

Using VS 2019 v 16.8.0
Test project on .NET Framework 4.8
Configured to Debug/Any CPU

After trying a bunch of things, the solution was

- Close Visual Studio
- Rename the folder holding your solution. For example: C:\Git\Solution to C:\Git\Solution2
- Open VS and load your solution. Try to run a test.

This worked for me, hope it works for you.

Comment: This worked for me. The error was strange after updating to latest version of VS2022. Installing any new libraries didnt help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to recap the solution brought forward by @Sushil earlier.

This is a known issue in Team Foundation Server 2015 RTM + Update 1 and will be fixed in Update 2, [reference](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2245723).

There is a workaround described by @Sushil [here](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2016/01/20/running-net-4-6-unit-tests-using-vstest-console-or-tfs-builds/), which includes adding a .runsettings file that forces the test runner to older .Net framework (please not that you have to specify it through the "Add/Edit Test Run" dialog as adding it directly in the build process editor will be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar issue and noticed somehow an `app.config` file had been added to my test project. Removing this config file fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 I just uninstall and reinstall NUnitTestAdapter or install new package like NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework package and problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my Unit test class was not public.

Ex:

`class ClientTests`

Error in Output:

`...\bin\Debug\Tests.dll] UTA001: TestClass attribute defined on non-public class ClientTests`

Correction:

`public class ClientTests`

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

[image]

I used these steps to successfully discover all my test cases and successfully run it:

- First go to Extensions and Updates, install NUnit3 Test Adapter. If
  you already have, just enable it.
- Restart your Visual Studio 2017, it will automatically prompt to
  install your extension, if a prompt says to end task to continue
  installing, just click "End Task".
- After that, rebuild your Test Project and all test cases will now be 
  identified and you can now start running your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way! Probably not the most orthodox but it did helped me out in a hurry:

1. Update the MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestAdapterFramework packages to the 1.4.0 from the Tools > NuGet Package Manager.
2. The clean the solution and run the tests again.

I don't think is anything particular with the version, but updating it certainly cleans whatever reference is bad in the solution/project.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `vstest.console.exe` with `--diag:diag.txt` and inspect the output. For me it was DLL load failures for test adapters from my working directory:

`TpTrace Information: 0 : 14976, 1, 2020/03/10, 15:34:22.120, 57158093583, vstest.console.exe, AssemblyResolver.OnResolve: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter: Failed to load assembly. Reason:System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Directory\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)`

`File name: 'file:///C:\Directory\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll' ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.`

I worked around this by adding `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` under `<runtime>` in vstest.console.exe.config

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into this issue as well, and I can with some confidence state that it's not one covered by any of the other answers here.

I've recently been writing some F# modules that (for reasons) have [signature files](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/signature-files). Again, for reasons, I've had to put unit tests into the same module.

When an F# source file is 'covered' by a signature file, only the declared values are exported. Thus, you have to explicitly declare each and every test in the signature file as well, otherwise you'll get the error message in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

One more random thing to do is to add the file `xunit.runner.json`.

Example configuration:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "appDomain": "ifAvailable",
  "shadowCopy": false,
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false,
  "maxParallelThreads": 1
}
```

Don't forget to include it in the project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In my case, this was the magical remedy.

Answer (score 1):

With NUnit3, in most cases all I had to do was to add

```
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.x.x" />
```

However in some of .NET Framework 4.7.2 **[SDK-style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview)** tests projects that wasn't enough.

The issue was with `PlatformTarget` project property. If unspecified it defaults to `AnyCPU`, however NUnit seems to always fail with

> No test is available in Foo.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

if it was left unspecified.

So, besides the PackageReference, I had to either:

- Just set `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>`.
- Explicitly set `<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>` (even though it is `AnyCPU` if unspecified) and then in Test tab set "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" to "x86".
  [image: Setting Processor Arhitecture for AnyCPU Projects]

Answer (score 0):

In my case Reinstalling Nunit3 Adapter, Deleting temp folders, Changing architecture and nothing worked. Its because of the Daemon Resharper caused the problem.

```
Add or Remove Programs> Find Resharper > Repair > Install again > Restart VS
```

That resolves the issues.

Answer (score 0):

After add the TestAdapterPath in the commander, it's worked for me:

```
vstest.console.exe Xom.Gci.Lvf.FileParserInvoker.UnitTests.dll /TestAdapterPath:"C:\****\****\{SolutionFolder}"
```

Comment: First things, you should make sure that the test case can be run in the VS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the tests were discovered but running resulted in *"Test not Available...*" and the (in)famous: *"Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."*

the error was independent of Visual Studio (tested from dotnet CLI tools and nearly naked UNit test) and it was only when targeting .NET 4.7.1.
dotnetcore app works fine.

also running tests with the Nuint3 CLI
`nunit3-console.exe Tests.csproj` shows the error:

*"Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found."*

the error was because the test-adapter could not be found on a (mapped) network drive or share and was solved by **copy it locally** and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was an old reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform`. You don't need an explicit reference to this package because `MSTest.TestFramework` has a transitive reference to this package with a **correct version**.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution only has one test file, check it has the `.cs` file extension.

I used the `dotnet` command to create a new test project for myself.
I hastily renamed the generated class (`UnitTest1.cs`) without the `.cs` file extension.

This is similar to @Jared-Beach's scenario: obviously no tests were found via the IDE nor the command line. Beyond the first three words, the rest of the error message will point you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had accidentally changed the Tests.cs file Compile action to 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I had loaded the same file twice.

1. Unload your project.
2. Check that you aren't loading the same file twice. If you are, just delete the file.

```xml
     <ItemGroup>
       <Compile Include="TitleBlockSizerTests.cs" />    
       <Compile Include="TitleBlock\TitleBlockSizerTests.cs" />   Notice how this file is listed twice?
     </ItemGroup>
```

Notice how the same file is included twice? Once that was removed, the tests ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your test adapter `.dll` file is located in the directory alongside the `*.Test.dll` files you intend to test. In my case, I needed to configure the `pathtoCustomTestAdapters` parameter of the `VSTest@3` task to point to the directory where the test adapter `.dll` was copied. In my scenario, this directory was `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\References\Client.Debug\`. This necessity arises from the specific logic of my solution, where nearly all generated `dll`s, including the test adapter's `dll`, are copied to this designated directory.