# Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am having an issue with the latest Visual Studio 2017 15.8.2.
For the life of me I can't seem to be able to run my build test. I don;t know what the ussue is, my code is fine it. I tried:

Deleting temp files

Reinstalling VS

Insalled NUnitTestAdapter (Still didn't help!)

I'm doing a C# coding course and I can't even continue my lessons becasuse of this!

Someone Please helpe me if you have had this problem and know of the solution buecause I am really gtting frustrated.

Thanks!

John

Comment: Check for errors in "Output" Window. You can open it in Debug->Windows->Output. Any error in build you can be confident in finding it there. Unless you know the root cause of the problem, trying different stuffs will not solve it.

Comment: see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790339/no-test-found-make-sure-that-installed-test-discoverers-executors-platform/56188658#56188658 if that helps or is applicable for you

Comment: For near future vs2019 users, I tried changing the platform targets in all possible combinations to get rid of the errors, cleaned and rebuilt N number of times. Nothing worked. I restarted and run `dotnet test` from git bash and then retried from the test explorer again. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the following setting in VS (Tools -> Options -> Test): "**For improved performance, only use test adapters in test assembly folder or as specified in runsettings file**".

Comment: This options appears to no longer exist - using VS2019

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my solution was being saved to a **OneDrive** location.

You can try this solution as given:

Recreating the solution directly on my **C:\ drive**, the tests then worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Although you have solution to your problem, it need not nessesarily solve OP's problem. This is more of a suggestion and should be posted in the comment section.

Comment: Sorry, Carbine, I didn't realise that there were 2 options of "answer" or "comment".  Agreed, I wasn't proposing this to be the definitive answer, just putting out a scenario with the same error message that I managed to clear.  I'm aware that there are a lot of people asking about this error message, with what look like different reasons, but most remain unanswered, so thought it worth throwing into the mix.  Feel free to convert it to a comment if you're able.