# Unable to run C# unit tests after cloning repository

Tags: c#, git, unit-testing

I am trying to run unit tests in a C# project that I have been working on, I have it in a repository in github and I cloned that repository to a desktop machine after creating it on my laptop.

When I try to run the unit tests I get this message in the console.

No test is available in C:\source\repos\server.csproj C:\source\repos\UnitTests\UnitTests.csproj. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

The paths here have been anonymized.

I am suspicious that I inappropriately included a file in my gitignore, but not sure it that is actually the case or what file might have been ignored incorrectly.  I used a sample that is available on [github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and haven't modified it.

Has anybody run into this and have any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: did you do a nuget restore? what type of project is it?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have not done a nuget restore.  It is a C# WebAPI project.

Comment: .net core or framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White, project is targeting Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Does the *.csproj file actually show up in your IDE solution tab?

Comment: @Frontear, both the server project that I'm working on and the unit tests project load without any problem and are displayed in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer tab.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Also did you check that the test settings / default processor architecture matches your project?

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell I'm using MSTest.  I don't have a test settings file set up.  The project isn't specifying a particular processor architecture, it's just setup to target any CPU, the IDE is using x86 as the default processor architecture.

Comment: @morris295 I'm not sure if we're talking about the same test settings. Please see the screenshot in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the test settings matches your processor architecture.

[image]

Comment: So in my reply to your comment I had checked this, but I compared it to the unit test project properties as well and assumed that the target processor there and this option were related.

Additionally, on my laptop where I created the project x86 is selected and the tests run without any problem.  I switched the default processor architecture to x64 on the desktop where I cloned this project and the unit tests are identified and run there fine now.  I'm not sure I understand why this is, both machines have 64 bit processors.  Regardless, thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer linked below explicitly indicates that if the target platform in the project properties is set to x64 then the default processor architecture needs to match.  The target platform in my test project is set to "Any CPU" so I'm even more uncertain why this would need to be changed in my case.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571848/1499043