# Errors when runnign unit tests in VS

Tags: c#

Every time I try to run my unit tests in VS with NUnit C#. I keep getting errors.

I have tried changing the framework and also the architecture. Yet still the same error.

Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 and platform X64. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
code_challenge.exe is built for Framework 4.7 and Platform X64.
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.

> [14/06/2019 18:23:15 Warning] No test is available in C:\Users\azabo\Documents\CSharp_code_challenge\CSharp_code_challenge\code_challenge\bin\x64\Debug\code_challenge.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
>   [14/06/2019 18:23:16 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:04.8107028) ==========

Comment: Please See This Limk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790339/no-test-found-make-sure-that-installed-test-discoverers-executors-platform

Comment: to solve it, I had to change it from NUnit to Microsoft test tools