# FSharp FsUnit No test is available in Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework

Tags: f#, fsunit

OK so a google search reveals 100s if not thousands of links but they are very old threads talking about NUnit and Nuget. I am not using these these tools.

I am writing a F# project with FsUnit and dotnet command line (no visual studio business).

I created a F# project like

```
dotnet new console -lang "F#" -o CustomerProject  
dotnet add package FsUnit
dotnet add package FsUnit.Xunit
dotnet add package Microsoft.TestPlatform
dotnet add package Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost
```

So my .fsproj file looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Customer.fs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomerTests.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>   
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FsUnit" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="FsUnit.Xunit" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" Version="17.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

In my project directory I have 2 files

`Customer.fs`

```
namespace MyProject.Customer
open System
type Customer = {
  Id : int
  isVip: bool
  Credit: decimal
}
module Domain =
  let getPurchases customer = 
    let purchases = if customer.Id % 2 = 0 then 120M else 80M in 
    (customer, purchases)

  let tryPromoteToVip purchases = 
    let (customer, amount) = purchases in
    if amount > 100M then {customer with isVip = true} else customer

  let increaseCreditIfVip customer = 
    let increase = if customer.isVip then 100M else 50M in
    {customer with Credit = customer.Credit + increase}

  let upgradeCustomer customer = 
    customer 
    |> getPurchases
    |> tryPromoteToVip
    |> increaseCreditIfVip
```

`CustomerTests.fs`

```
module CustomerTests
open Xunit
open FsUnit
open MyProject.Customer
open MyProject.Customer.Domain

module ``When upgrading customer`` = 
  let customerVIP = {Id = 1; isVip = true; Credit = 0.0M}
  let customerSTD = {Id = 2; isVip = false; Credit = 100.0M}
  [<Fact>]
  let ``should give VIP cstomer more credit`` () =
    let expected = {customerVIP with Credit = customerVIP.Credit + 100.0M }
    let actual = upgradeCustomer customerVIP
    actual |> should equal expected
```

yet when I run `dotnet test` from the command line I get an error

```
No test is available in /Users/user/code/fsharp/CustomerProject/bin/Debug/net6.0/CustomerProject.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using /TestAdapterPath command. Example  /TestAdapterPath:<pathToCustomAdapters>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761136/344223), you need to add an xUnit runner to your project as well. And according to [the xUnit documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netcore/cmdline#create-project), you have to add `xunit.runner.visualstudio`, even if you just want to use `dotnet test`:

```
dotnet add package xunit.runner.visualstudio
```

(There's also an `xunit.runner.console` package on NuGet, but I think it's just for old .NET Framework projects.)