# docker compose file not working: replicas Additional property replicas is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker version: 17.03.1-ce

Trying to get the docker-compose.yml working from the getting started tutorials.

```
version: "3"
   services:
     web:
       image: tuhina/friendlyhello:2.0
     deploy:
       replicas: 5
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: "0.1"
           memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      networks:
        - webnet
    networks:
      webnet:
```

Getting this error:

```
replicas Additional property replicas is not allowed
```

What have I typed in wrong?

Thanks.

edit: docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245

Comment: What version of compose are you using?

Comment: @RobertMoskal : Thanks! - edited the question to add docker-compose version

Comment: This error also can be caused if you specify old version like I did "3.6". You must bump it to "3.8".

Comment: In my case, it was giving error "(root) Additional property service is not allowed". I changed "service" to "services"

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Indentation is critical in docker-compose.yml. The way you have it set up, "deploy" is a service, which is not intended. The deploy section is intended to specify information about how the "web" service should be deployed. The following allows `docker-compose up` and `docker stack deploy web --compose-file docker-compose.yml` to run successfully for me:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: tuhina/friendlyhello:2.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: '50M'
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

Answer (score 29):

This happened to me because I was using docker-compose version 2 but my docker-compose.yml file was for version 1.

My docker-compose.yml file was initially like this:

```
web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
```

So when I would run `docker-compose up` , I was getting this error:

```
(root) Additional property web is not allowed
```

I downgraded to docker-compose version 1 like this:

```
docker-compose disable-v2
```

Now it was working. To get it to work for v2, first I enabled v2:

```
docker-compose enable-v2
```

Then I updated my docker-compose.yml like below because docker-compose v2, `web` can not be the top/outermost value.

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
```

I checked the version of docker-compose I was using:

```
docker-compose --version
```

I found that I was running version `v2.2.3` , before the upgrade it had been  `1.29.2`.

These days docker-compose comes as part of docker itself. Try below command:

```
docker compose version
```

Comment: Thank you, I've referenced this answer many times

Comment: on macos, I get `"host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings` after  doing `docker-compose disable-v2`, it work well on linux but not mac

Comment: Can you do: docker compose version . Ideally you shouldn't disable V2, it's only for demonstrative purposes.

Answer (score 10):

For people stumbling upon this question; double check the property name.

I used `enviroment` instead of `environment`

Answer (score -1):

Second most voted suggestion worked for me.

Check your version of docker-compose - `docker compose version`

If it is version 2 or above then docker-compose written in basic format will not work if you use `docker compose up` command.

So make sure to disable the version 2 or above to test docker-compose.yml file of older versions with command: `docker-compose disable-v2`

Now test with `docker compose up` command & observe compose will work. Check image below for more info.

[image]

**Note**: Do not forget to enable the latest version with command: `docker-compose enable-v2`