# Additional property args is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a issue with this code. When i write in terminal docker-compose up --build. Terminal show me this issue:

```
C:\Users\ingbr\OneDrive\Documentos\Server Minecraft> docker-compose up --build
services.minecraft-server Additional property args is not allowed
```

I don't find a solution

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  minecraft-server:
    build:
     context: .
    args:
      RAM_AMOUNT: ${RAM_AMOUNT} 
    volumes:
       - .server-data:/server
    ports:
          - 25565:25565
          - 25575:25575
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
          
volumes:
    server-data:
```

Comment: `args` needs to be put under `build` as can be seen here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args

Comment: I found that solution on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566427/docker-compose-file-not-working-replicas-additional-property-replicas-is-not-al I hope it works.

Comment: Also note that a dot in this line: `- .server-data:/server` means local folder instead of named volume. Do you want to use a named volume or a bind mount? Try running `docker-compose config` to see the difference in the parsed configuration with and without the dot.

Answer (score 8):

The "args" is one of "build" parameters, so your script should be like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  minecraft-server:
    build:
     context: .
     args:
       RAM_AMOUNT: ${RAM_AMOUNT} 
    volumes:
       - .server-data:/server
    ports:
          - 25565:25565
          - 25575:25575
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
          
volumes:
    server-data:
```