Docker-Problem: docker compose file not working: replicas Additional property replicas is not allowed
I created a docker-compose.yml file based on the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mwWxgfZ7Zc
Content:
version: '3.3'
service:
  web:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    conteiner_name: php81
    volumes:
    - ./php:/var/www/html
    ports:
    -  8000:80

After docker-compose up i get the message docker compose file not working: replicas Additional property replicas is not allowed
How to fix the problem?
Look her 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566427/docker-compose-file-not-working-replicas-additional-property-replicas-is-not-al' but it don't help.
