# Setting ENV variable from python script in dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set an ENV equal to a python script output in my dockerfile. Due to layering, I'm unable to find a way to have them on the same layer. I've also been unable to find a way set the variable directly equal to the script, I can't seem to find how to run the script in the same line.

The python is a simple print, called test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("xd")
```

So far, I've tried a few versions of the below in my dockerfile to set the ENV to the script:

```
ENV testvar=test.py
ENV testvar=$(test.py)
ENV testvar='python test.py'
```

Is there anyway to set ENV testvar equal to the script in one step or a way to ensure the script and setting the variable are done on the same layer?

Comment: Get your output string, then set the environment variable in a call to the function for setting the value in your script?

Comment: If you are trying to call the script named test.py from something else, then I assume you could get the value in your script and eval that from wherever it is being used. Docker would let you RUN something at a different step in your dockerfile.

Comment: I have tried that:

`RUN python test.py

ENV testvar=test.py`
but because it starts a new layer each time, the ENV doesn't see the script result

Comment: Set it externally and write to the file, then run your dockerfile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213837/dockerfile-output-of-run-instruction-into-a-variable

Comment: Didn't get the question properly. Are you trying to execute the python script inside Dockerfile and store the output in `testvar`? If so, then it is not possible, and not recommended. ENV variables are set before the docker engine runs Dockerfile, so you cannot go back and re-set it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to place this in my entrypoint and set it to a k8's secret (also set in the entrypoint) to get it to other pods.

Another option that was tried was placing the script output into a txt file, setting the variable to that file, then deleting it.