# Docker error: no such file or directory, open '/package.json' with NestJs application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm trying to run a node image(with nestJS application) inside docker but I have this error:

```
*$ docker compose build
[+] Building 7.3s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 747B                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.22.4-alpine                                        6.6s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 10.04kB                                                                          0.0s
 => [development 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.22.4-alpine@sha256:78be4f61c7a0f00cc9da47e3ba2f1bacf9ba  0.0s
 => CACHED [development 2/6] WORKDIR /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [development 3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [development 4/6] RUN npm install --only=development                                               0.0s
 => [development 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                0.1s
 => ERROR [development 6/6] RUN cd /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend && npm run build                            0.5s
------
 > [development 6/6] RUN cd /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend && npm run build:
#0 0.507 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#0 0.508 npm ERR! syscall open
#0 0.508 npm ERR! path /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend/package.json
#0 0.509 npm ERR! errno -2
#0 0.510 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/project/sawtooth-tuna/backend/package.json'
#0 0.510 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#0 0.510 npm ERR! enoent
#0 0.516
#0 0.516 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#0 0.516 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-17T00_58_30_434Z-debug.log
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend && npm run build]: exit code: 254
```

I have read all the available posts related to this topic. But no luck -

**My docker file**

```
# Download base image
FROM node:12.22.4-alpine As development

# Define Base Directory
WORKDIR /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend

# Copy and restore packages
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=development

# Copy all other directories
COPY . .

# Setup base command
RUN npm run build

# # second phase
FROM node:12.22.4-alpine As production

# Declaring working directory
WORKDIR /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

#Copy build artifacts
COPY --from=builder /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend/dist ./
COPY --from=builder /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend/config ./config

# Start the server
CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

As I am using docker-compose -

```
 tunachain-backend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
    image: hyperledger/tunachain-backend
    container_name: tunachain-backend
    volumes:
      - .:/project/sawtooth-tuna/backend
      - /project/sawtooth-tuna/backend/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
      - 9229:9229
```

My project structure -

```
    backend -
        NestJs application code
        Dockerfile
    docker-compose
```

- Any suggestion or any hint(how should I debug the issue). Fairly new with docker ---

Comment: You copied the package*.json to ```./```  Is that where it's supposed to be?

Comment: ./ - is the working directory, right? If yes then the packag.json file should be there

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if ```./``` is the working directory.  Is it possible to display what ```./```  is right before that line?

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to do that, when you are building an image!

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213837/dockerfile-output-of-run-instruction-into-a-variable, you use ```RUN echo $(ls -1 ./)```

Comment: No, it's not working. Not printing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the problem is, how and where I was copying my package*.json to the destination folder. As My `docker compose` file is in the root directory and my `Dockerfile` is in the `backend` folder. The copy command should look like `backend/package*.json ./`.

Also, for debugging the issue. I just find my last successful step image. And `sh` into it and tried to run the step(which was causing the problem) inside that image, to get more insights.

Hope somone in future will get some help from this.