# How to edit file inside docker which is exited?

Tags: docker

I edited a file in a running docker container and restarted it, unfortunately my last edit was not correct. So every time I start the container with:

```
docker start <containerId>
```

It always exits immediately.

Now I can not even modify my edit back, since

```
docker exec -it <containerId> bash
```

can only run on a running docker.

The question is how can I change it and restart the container now? Or I had to abandon it and start a new container from an existing image?

Comment: You can't, you will need to start from a fresh container

Comment: You *can*, but probably *shouldn't* unless you really know that it's what you want to be doing. (See below)

Comment: While this can be useful in developer test conditions, I'd consider having to do this a smell. Ideally, it should be possible to throw a away the container and start fresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't supply any details regarding your container's purpose, or what you modified. Conceptually, you could create the file that needs to be modified in a place on your filesystem and [mount that file into the container as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) when you start it, like:

```
docker run -it -v /Users/<path_to_file>:<container_path_to_file> <container>
```

*Hovever*, this is bad form, as your container loses portability at that point without [committing a new image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

Ideally, changes that need to be made inside of a Docker container are made in the Dockerfile, and the container image re-built. This way, your initial, working container state is represented in your Dockerfile code, making your configuration repeatable, portable, and immutable.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I just think changing a config and rebuild an image is someshow slow. I want to see whether a change is valid, so I edit it directly inside container and see the result for debug.

Comment: Sure, and the best way I can think to do that is with a volume mount, as above. If you've ruined a file in an existing container image, using that technique to replace the bad file with a working one will at least get you into the container. You can then test your changes by editing the file outside the container, and not worry that you're going to lock yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

The file system of exited containers can still be changed. The preferable way is *probably*:

```sh
docker cp <fixedFile> <containerId>:<brokenFile>
```

But you can also circumvent `docker` completely; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028759/539599).