# How to see docker image contents

Tags: docker

I did a docker pull and can list the image that's downloaded. I want to see the contents of this image. Did a search on the net but no straight answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exploring Docker container's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system)

Comment: Not a dupe. Viewing the container and the image are not the same thing. You may want to view the initial filesystem or even validate that there is nothing malicious inside the image before it gets a chance to run.

Comment: if you could not run the image as container you can use a tool like drive (https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) or you can use docker save to export the image as tar file. Then you can explore the tar or with dive you can asap explore the image.

Comment: Not a dupe but you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40324326/5641227

Answer (score 1000, accepted):

If the image contains a shell, you can run an interactive shell container using that image and explore whatever content that image has.  If `sh` is not available, the busybox `ash` shell might be.

For instance:

```
docker run -it image_name sh
```

Or following for images with an `entrypoint`

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh image_name
```

Or if you want to see how the image was built, meaning the steps in its `Dockerfile`, you can:

```
docker image history --no-trunc image_name > image_history
```

The steps will be logged into the `image_history` file.

Comment: Thanks. First one is what I am looking for. Basically explore the folders.

Comment: I'm trying to see the contents of an image that is created using "FROM scratch" and there is no shell available. Is there any other way to see the contents? The image I'm trying to see is portainer/portainer.

Comment: Is it possible that someone see the contents of the image without spawning a container? Or can we assume that it is safe from all unless they have rights to spawn a container from it?

Comment: combining what's told before "for a windows container with entrypoint": `docker run -it --entrypoint cmd <image_name>` will work.

Comment: @JuanHernandez, yes, you can dump the full contents of the image as indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677219/320594.

Comment: Can I double like this?

Comment: This answer is not good because it depends on having a shell inside the image, which is not always the case. The `docker create` answer is the best one for the question if you're not interested in the examination of each image layer independently.

Comment: Hi after `docker run it xxx` I'm able to get an interactive shell, just wondering what's the command to print out all the folder/contents in this image?

Comment: @JuanHernandez the "scratch" image in docker is empty, it is meant to start a new image from nothing.

Comment: The first two solutions do not work with images that do not have a shell. The exact reason why I want to list image contents is that I can't find a shell executable in the image...

Answer (score 569):

You should not start a container just to see the image contents. For instance, you might want to look for malicious content, not run it. Use "create" instead of "run";

```
docker create --name="tmp_$$" image:tag
docker export tmp_$$ | tar t
docker rm tmp_$$
```

Comment: The 2nd line above just lists the file-system content.  If you want to get all the files as a tar you can replace it with something like `docker export tmp_$$ > image-fs.tar`.

Comment: What will be the 2nd line for Windows OS? The `docker export tmp_$$ | tar t` will not work.

Comment: @Alexei Marinichenko `tar` might not installed on your machine. Try `tar --help` for checking it.

Comment: This also works if there is no shell in the container

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko you can use the `-o` parameter to specify the file to write to. E.g. `docker export -o c:\temp\tmp_$$.tar tmp_$$`.

Comment: Still it will not work (on Windows containers): "the daemon on this operating system does not support exporting Windows containers"
`docker save <image> -o image.tar` does work however.

Comment: This solution works better than `docker export` or `docker save` when there is no interest in examining every layer of the image independently. This is the correct answer to the OP question.

Comment: The docker create command errors for me with a `No command specified`. putting a dummy command like `ls` at the end (even if the command would fail if the container were started) seems to work.

```docker create --name="tmp_$$" image:tag ls```

Comment: You don't need to assign a name for the created container. `docker create` will generate and output container id to stdout and this can be used as argument to `docker export` and `docker rm`.

Comment: hi `docker export tmp_$$ > image-fs.tar` after this command, is this tar file been exported on my local machine? Or do I need an extra command to download it to my local machine so that I can browse?

Comment: I confirm this is the best working solution. It gives you all the files inside the container without running it!!

Comment: I just see half a dozen "layer.tar" files (docker 20.10, API 1.41). The command only goes down one level.

Comment: To extract the contents of the specific directory replace the second command with docker cp tmp_$$:/src ./des. works like a charm with distro-less images

Answer (score 401):

The accepted answer here is problematic, because there is no guarantee that an image will have any sort of interactive shell.  For example, the [drone/drone](https://hub.docker.com/r/drone/drone/) image contains on a single command `/drone`, *and* it has an `ENTRYPOINT` as well, so this will fail:

```
$ docker run -it drone/drone sh
FATA[0000] DRONE_HOST is not properly configured
```

And this will fail:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh drone/drone
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

This is not an uncommon configuration; many minimal images contain only the binaries necessary to support the target service.  Fortunately, there are mechanisms for exploring an image filesystem that do not depend on the *contents* of the image.  The easiest is probably the `docker export` command, which will export a *container* filesystem as a tar archive.  So, start a container (it does not matter if it fails or not):

```
$ docker run -it drone/drone sh
FATA[0000] DRONE_HOST is not properly configured
```

Then use `docker export` to export the filesystem to `tar`:

```
$ docker export $(docker ps -lq) | tar tf -
```

The `docker ps -lq` there means "give me the id of the most recent docker container".  You could replace that with an explicit container name or id.

Comment: You can also use the out parameter as in `docker export $(docker ps -lq) -o foo.tar`

Comment: If you are like me, wondering what the `-` means in `tar tf -` : it's to tell tar that the "file" (*f flag*) to read is `stdin`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although it should lead with the proper command.

Comment: This works on a container, not an image. Trivially fixed: `docker image save $IMAGE | tar -tf -`. The logic is the same: Docker needs to combine layers, higher-level layers can overwrite files from lower layers.

Answer (score 247):

```
docker save nginx > nginx.tar
tar -xvf nginx.tar
```

Following files are present:

- manifest.json – Describes filesystem layers and name of json file that has the Container properties.
- .json – Container properties
- – Each “layerid” directory contains json file describing layer property and filesystem associated with that layer. Docker stores Container images as layers to optimize storage space by reusing layers across images.

https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/06/11/looking-inside-container-images/

OR

you can use **dive** to view the image content interactively with TUI

[image]

https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Comment: This seems like the most useful answer to me, as you don't have to start a container to get the files.

Comment: Absolutely agree @AlecThomas - and to take it a step further, why do I even need `docker` just to see the contents of what is, essentially, just a different type of archive file.

Comment: good answer, I would also specify the tag: `docker save --output nginx.tar nginx:latest`, otherwise, according to the doc, it will contain "all parent layers, and all tags + versions"

Comment: This should be upvoted as this is probably the only way to explore internals if you don't have any of Unix utils inside. Also this way doesn't require the creation of a container.

Comment: how did I survive without this tool in the last 5 years ?

Comment: is it possible to see the content? like the script in the docker using Dive?

Comment: `is it possible to see the content? like the script in the docker using Dive?`

Not yet, see related feature request https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/issues/224

Comment: I only see lots of layers.tar file not the actual content

Answer (score 43):

**EXPLORING DOCKER IMAGE**!

1. Figure out what kind of shell is in there `bash` or `sh`...

Inspect the image first: `docker inspect name-of-container-or-image`

Look for `entrypoint` or `cmd` in the JSON return.

2. Then do: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash name-of-image`

once inside do: `ls -lsa` or any other shell command like: `cd ..`

The `-it` stands for interactive... and TTY. The `--rm` stands for remove container after run.

If there are no common tools like `ls` or `bash` present and you have access to the `Dockerfile` simple add the common tool as a layer.
example (alpine Linux):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

And when you don't have access to the `Dockerfile` then just copy/extract the files from a newly created container and look through them:

```
docker create <image>  # returns container ID the container is never started.
docker cp <container ID>:<source_path> <destination_path>
docker rm <container ID>
cd <destination_path> && ls -lsah
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that, as discussed in the accepted answer, there's no guarantee that your image has *any* shell in it. Or `ls`. Or really any common tools at all.

Comment: Yes, this assumes common tools are in there. You could of course always add a shell if you are allowed to ill add that layer to the answer and explain how to extract the files otherwise.

Comment: docker cp <container ID>:<source_path> <destination_path> what do you mean by source path? as the assumption here is that we haven't run the container and do not know its full contents.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to list the files in an image without starting a container :

```
docker create --name listfiles <image name>
docker export listfiles | tar -t
docker rm listfiles
```

Answer (score 17):

I tried this tool - https://github.com/wagoodman/dive
I found it quite helpful to explore the content of the docker image.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

To list the detailed content of an image you have to run `docker run --rm image/name ls -alR` where `--rm` means remove as soon as exits form a container.

[image]

Comment: This assumes that the image has `ls` available and in the `PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Oneliner, no docker run (based on responses above)

```
IMAGE=your_image docker create --name filelist $IMAGE command && docker export filelist | tar tf - | tree --fromfile . && docker rm filelist
```

Same, but report tree structure to result.txt

```
IMAGE=your_image docker create --name filelist $IMAGE command && docker export filelist | tar tf - | tree --noreport --fromfile . | tee result.txt && docker rm filelist
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check the image contents without running it you can do this:

```
$ sudo bash
...
$ cd /var/lib/docker  # default path in most installations
$ find . -iname a_file_inside_the_image.ext
... (will find the base path here)
```

This works fine with the [current default BTRFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/).

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the following dirty way to get the contents.

1. save the image

   docker save imagename > imagename.tar
2. Open imagename.tar with any of the un archiving tools.
3. Viola!!

Answer (score 1):

We can try a simpler one as follows:

```
docker image inspect image_id
```

This worked in Docker version:

```
DockerVersion": "18.05.0-ce"
```

Comment: This doesn't show the _contents_; it only shows the layers, etc., that went into building the image.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free open source tool called Anchore-CLI that you can use to scan container images.  This command will allow you to list all files in a container image

```
anchore-cli image content myrepo/app:latest files
```

https://anchore.com/opensource/

EDIT: not available from anchore.com anymore, It's a python program you can install from https://github.com/anchore/anchore-cli

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is nota  very straight forward approach but this one worked for me.
I had an ECR Repo (Amazon Container Service Repository) whose code i wanted to see.

1. First we need to save the repo you want to access as a tar file. In my case the command went like - **docker save** .dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<name_of_repo>:image-tag > saved-repo.tar
2. UNTAR the file using the command - **tar -xvf** saved-repo.tar. You could see many folders and files
3. Now try to find the file which contain the code you are looking for (if you know some part of the code)
   Command for searching the file - **grep -iRl** "string you want to search" ./

This will make you reach the file. It can happen that even that file is tarred, so untar it using the command mentioned in step 2.

If you dont know the code you are searching for, you will need to go through all the files that you got after step 2 and this can be bit tiring.

All the Best !

Comment: When I try to do this, I get the following error: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-385434031: read-only file system. Is that complaining about my local file system, or something about the image I've just pulled from ECR?

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly said you need to make a container from an image before you can export it, however there are other ways.

One of such ways is exporting the image using the [build command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/).

By default the build command makes another image, which is not useful for us, instead, we can use the [`--output`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/#output) to specify that we want a folder or a `.tar` of the contents of the image:

```
echo 'from node:18-alpine' | docker build --output type=tar,dest=test-docker.tar -
```

You now get a tar file in the directory the docker build command is run, containing the exact file structure of your image, including the file owner information and original timestamps:

```
$ tar -tvf test-docker.tar | grep node | head
drwxr-sr-x 1000/1000         0 2024-03-16 04:31 home/node/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:32 tmp/v8-compile-cache-0/10.2.154.26-node.28/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0         2200240 2024-03-16 04:32 tmp/v8-compile-cache-0/10.2.154.26-node.28/zSoptzSyarn-v1.22.19zSbinzSyarn.js.BLOB
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              88 2024-03-16 04:32 tmp/v8-compile-cache-0/10.2.154.26-node.28/zSoptzSyarn-v1.22.19zSbinzSyarn.js.MAP
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:31 usr/local/bin/corepack -> ../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0        94888944 2024-02-15 13:51 usr/local/bin/node
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:31 usr/local/bin/nodejs -> /usr/local/bin/node
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:31 usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:31 usr/local/bin/npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
drwxr-sr-x 0/0               0 2024-03-16 04:31 usr/local/include/node/
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just run the following code to see the content of docker image:

```
docker exec -it <image_id> sh
```

Answer (score -3):

With Docker EE for Windows (17.06.2-ee-6 on Hyper-V Server 2016) all contents of Windows Containers can be examined at `C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\` path of the host OS.

No special mounting needed.

Folder prefix can be found by container id from `docker ps -a` output.