# How to get the original files of Docker Image?

Tags: docker, extract

How can I get the files from which a Docker Image was built?

"docker save" gives me a .tar file that expands to a much larger and more cryptic thing.

"docker export" only works on Containers, not Images.

I found a similar question here: [How to see docker image contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769315/how-to-see-docker-image-contents)
but it doesn't explain how to actually get those files extracted to your hard drive, only how to look at them.

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files you interested out from the docker container.

Comment: That works only for containers though, not for Images. Is there a way to just get the entire folder that the Image was built from?