# How to run local Docker Image

Tags: windows, docker

I have an image that I want to run on my local machine. I took this image from my friend and not from docker-hub or any repository. The file shared is in ".img" format.

I am able to import this image on docker but unable to run.

What I did:

1. Compress the image file from ".img" format to ".tar.gz" format so that the docker image can be imported. I used 7-zip tool to convert this.
2. From my local I imported the docker image using this new file(.tar.gz)<
3. Trying to run this imported image but fails.

Commands Executed:

```
PS C:\Users\C61464> docker import .\Desktop\regchange.tar.gz
sha256:a0008215897dd1a7db205c191edd0892f484d230d8925fd09e79d8878afa2743
PS C:\Users\C61464> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
SIZE
<none>              <none>              7fdbbdcc59c4        2 minutes ago       1.05GB
PS C:\Users\C61464> docker tag 7fdbbdcc59c4 bwise:version1.0
PS C:\Users\C61464> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
SIZE
bwise               version1.0          7fdbbdcc59c4        3 minutes ago       1.05GB
PS C:\Users\C61464> docker run -p 8888:80 bwise:version1.0
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I searched a lot for this error and found that for running we need to specify the path used while creating the image(In Dockerfile) but I am not sure as I am new to docker. Am I doing something wrong or I need to have the docker file to run this image?

Comment: It doesn't immediately look like the file you have is an exported Docker image (that wouldn't usually be named `*.img`); you might have more luck using the system that originally created it.

Comment: @DavidMaze .. Thanks .. I can check that with my friend but the strange thing for me is the docker import works. Incase of invalid docker image shouldn't it give me an error ?

Comment: If you have to use `docker import`, it's not a valid image.  (`docker load` would be somewhat more typical but still unusual.)  The error you're getting is because the image you have doesn't have a default `CMD` at all, but all of the standard base images define _something_ as a command (generally a shell).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Docker Image you have had no CMD or ENTRYPOINT defined when it was built, so the docker daemon doesn't know what to do with the image

Try doing

```
docker run -it -p 8888:80 bwise:version1.0 sh
```

(if it's a *nix based image). That should start an interactive shell.

You can do:

```
docker run -p 8888:80 bwise:version1.0 {command_you_want_to_run}
```

On the image when starting it.

Comment: For command "docker run -it -p 8888:80 bwise:version1.0 sh " it fails with another error but I assume this is something to do with the mount flags in docker service. I am using windows 10. Error : 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\":  executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: @DhaneshAgrawal Try /bin/sh instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen .. The same .. Command : PS C:\Users\C61464> docker run -it -p 8888:80 bwise:version1.0 /bin/sh Output : C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

Comment: Is the image you're running *nix based? What is the OS your image is based on ?

Comment: @pixie999 .. I will check if the image is based on *nix or not. The OS is shown as "linux" when I run command : docker inspect image_name

Comment: Hello ,
How to run/install a docker image.
I pulled an image from drive. so i have docker image
i have docker already installed

Answer (score 0):

The docker image may be broken.

Look inside.  See suggestions how to in [How to see docker image contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44769315/53897)

Comment: 1) docker image history --no-trunc image_name > image_history : only gives the time and sha ID when this image was run.
2) docker inspect image_name : Gives the config with null values for cmd, entrypoint and details about os,architecture,layers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to inspect your image

```
docker inspect [docker-image-name]
```

Inspect you will see base image and other info about that image

Comment: Hello ,
How to run/install a docker image.
I pulled an image from drive. so i have docker image
i have docker already installed