# Where "sh" comes from in the command $ docker run -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1 sh

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers

Based on the documentation from Docker, I noticed that if I want to inspect the content files of my Elasticsearch container, I need to use the `run` command with the `-it` tag. However, after some Googling someone also recommended that I use `sh` in my command (link in background section). I understand that `sh` is used to create a shell for me to interact with, but how does it work under the hood? Does it link together with the tty that is created from the `-it` tag? Is `sh` referring to the linux-based `sh` command, a docker `sh` command, a path, or something entirely different? How does docker know what I mean by `sh` and where can I find documentation on this?

I used this post as a reference for knowing what command to use:
[How to see docker image contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769315/how-to-see-docker-image-contents?newreg=a30e624217a44b38a08ac50526378b22)

The command I mentioned in my post:

```
$ docker run -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1 sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh` denotes the command to run within the container (strictly speaking, this is only true if there is no ENTRYPOINT specified in the image).

There must be a `sh` executable contained in the image in the PATH. Alternatively you may specify any other executable that is available in the image.