# Docker: get a list of files installed in image

Tags: docker

I am creating a docker image based on Centos:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install <package>
```

Is there a way I can get a listing of the files/directories installed in the image, beyond the initial centos starting image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see docker image contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769315/how-to-see-docker-image-contents)

Comment: A good way to see this might be to compare the initial image and your image via `container-diff` from google (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff) it supports file changes via the `--file` parameter. 

PS: I wrote a little python dependency differ here https://link.medium.com/ptfuH7Xaf0

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will find the answer here: [How to see docker image contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769315/how-to-see-docker-image-contents/44769468)

```bash
docker image history --no-trunc image_name > image_history
```

Should give you the history. Be aware to take the correct image. The `RUN` should create a new image file.