# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused:exec:"sh":executable file not found in $PATH:unknown

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm using command:

```
sudo docker exec -it 70f898d63375 sh
```

to enter inside my docker with container id mentioned above. But I'm getting error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "ls": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

I tried other similar solutions for it like changing sh to bash, /bin/bash,/bin/sh, //bin//sh,//bin//bash, but none of them worked. Further, none of the similar solutions were regarding

> container_linux.go:370:

Help me with it.

Comment: There is no guarantee that an image has an interactive shell for you to use. If you want to examine the files in the image to see if you can spot one, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53481010/1899640). If there isn't one, you can create a new image that contains one. PS: the `370` is a line number and not an error code, so you don't need to find answers with the same number

Comment: Can you provide your image's `Dockerfile`?