# WebSphere Traditional docker container not starting because of JVM Setting

Tags: docker, websphere-8

I did a mistake in JVM arguments setting in WebSphere after restarting docker container is not starting . I know because of my modification but How can I solve that ?  I need to access docker container and without starting (I think) I could not do that .

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`docker run -d your-image tail -f /dev/null`

It will keep your docker running.

Then you can do:

`docker exec -it your-container-id bash`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Jorge Chavez  I already run my container and I'm just using docker run <MyContainerId> and if I run docker run -d your-image tail -f /dev/null it will create new container right? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please follow [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system) and check final answer . My question is the same but the command "docker inspect -f {{.Mounts}} MyContainerId "returning [] for me. I do not know why?

Comment: Yes, it will keep your container alive.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by copying missing jar files in docker container by using docker cp {my.jar} {myContainerId}://WebSpherePath/ {my.jar}  but I'm still thinking that this is the only way to keep your container alive or not?

Comment: Adding the ``tail -f /dev/null`` at the end is for keeping your container alive even if your app fails to start. Try to modify your Dockerfile, to perform the [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) operations in there for your jar files. [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)