# Qemu register binaries using docker image

Tags: docker, qemu

I'm testing out `multiarch/qemu-user-static` docker image which should generate binaries to build images for different CPU architecture.

I tried the following command on my macbook:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register
```

and one of the output is:

```
Setting /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static as binfmt interpreter for arm
sh: write error: File exists
```

It looks like the generated file already exists.

My problem is that I can't find `qemu-arm-static` in `/usr/bin/`.

So, where was it saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This container will change the files in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` of host machine as the container will share the kernel of host.

The candidate the script in container is:

```
qemu_target_list="i386 i486 alpha arm armeb sparc32plus ppc ppc64 ppc64le m68k \
mips mipsel mipsn32 mipsn32el mips64 mips64el \
sh4 sh4eb s390x aarch64 aarch64_be hppa riscv32 riscv64 xtensa xtensaeb microblaze 
microblazeel"
```

All above will be registered, but in fact, in host, some one already registered there, so you will get `file already exists.`

As the script not exit, so you can bypass these errors.

BTW: You can use `docker run -it --rm --privileged --entrypoint /bin/sh multiarch/qemu-user-static:register` to enter into the container to have a look of these scripts if you want. According to its dockerfile, it will first call `/register` shell script.

Comment: if I try to do on my mac cd /proc/sys/fs/ I get cd: no such file or directory: /proc/sys/fs/

Comment: See [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install), for mac, docker use hyperkit, so there is a virtual machine on your mac acted as host, not the real physical OS