# What's the default location for Zeppelin notebooks in the Windows file system?

Tags: windows, apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

On a fresh Win10 machine with fresh docker, the following command instantiates Zeppelin:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
```

... allowing me to create a new notebook using the GUI at http://localhost:8080/#/

[image]

... but where are these notebooks stored? What's the default path to their directory so that I can `git init` and get to work? With Jupyter there is a 'tree' showing clearly the location/path of all notebooks; I don't see one for Zep and an hour's Googling has not been informative.

The GUI's 'Notebook Repos' button doesn't seem to help:
[image]

Comment: eg this appears to assume we know where the `zeppelin` folder & configs reside; on my system they're nowhere to be seen! https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.5.6-incubating/storage/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20816397/8012789) I've been able to view the specific .json file representing my notebook. This answers the Q of where zeppelin notebooks exist in Docker images; leaving unanswered the question of where they exist in the Windows filesystem when NOT using Docker.

If using Docker (as recommended by the [Zeppelin docs](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html)) this is the recipe for finding a notebook file:

```
# first steps are taken in Powershell
docker ps # displays an image id for use in next line
docker commit <image_id_here> mysnapshot 
docker run -t -i mysnapshot  /bin/bash

# now in bash inside the Docker image
root@91f4bf850583:/zeppelin# ll notebook/2E6D1WBGT/note.json
```

... so (if using Docker) the best way to version-control a notebook is by using Docker versioning. This is quite different to Jupyter's approach where one can run individual .ipynb notebooks locally and version-control each of them. Having answered my own question I feel greatly more informed about Docker and the differences between Jupyter vs Zeppelin. Very curious to know if anyone can solve the original question of where notebooks are stored if running in Windows WITHOUT Docker