# What is the proper shebang to use in a python script to be used in a Dockerfile against the official python:3 docker image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, jinja2

I'm writing a python3 script that is used in a Dockerfile. It is based on the official `python:3` docker hub image. I've found that I get mixed results depending on what `#!` line I use in the script. The generally accepted `#!/usr/bin/env python3` actually doesn't work. If I used the `/usr/sbin/python3` like is the default on my system, it can't find some imported dependencies that I've done a `pip3 install` on right above. It seems that `/usr/local/bin/python3` is the first python3 in the path inside the container. I'd like the script to run comfortably both inside and outside the container. For now I'm just calling the script with python3 in the Dockerfile and skipping the whole mess.

How do I setup the SheBang for best compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this shebang simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: On many systems that will get you a very dated Python 2.  I’d expect the form in the question to be correct.

Comment: this is not answering the OP question, he's correct that this shabang would give him the wrong version of python

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `#!/usr/bin/python3`
My docker container's `FROM` command is `python:3.9`

I found this out by [poking around inside the docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40324326/11878912)

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash name-of-image
```

I used `cd` and `ls` to find the python installation and used that path.