# Copy file from container to local filesystem

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, linux-mint

**History**:

My docker build file worked for years, without any problem, on my Linux Mint VM. When I needed to recreate the VM, I installed everything again, including docker.io.
I'm taking a beating with this error. I already verified that the final file is inside the docker image, but when I try to copy it to a directory external to the container, it says that it does not exist.

I followed the guidelines at [Exploring Docker container's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system) and verified that the file was in fact in the container.

**Environment**:

- Linux Mint 19 (Tricia)
- Docker installed by snap

**Command**:

```
docker cp {CONTAINER_ID}:/container_path /local_path
```

[image]

**Problem**:

```
stat /container_path: no such file or directory
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to uninstall the docker by **snap** and install it again by **apt**. This solution still lacks more information, as it is not known if the problem was really caused by the version of the docker installed by **snap**.

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo apt install docker.io
```