# How to list all directories and files inside docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-container, docker-image

Following is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-windowsservercore
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip download -r requirements.txt -d packages
```

To get list of files in the image, I have tried both the following options, but there is error:

```
encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: 
The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: 
{"CommandLine":"dir","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app"......
```

1. Run `docker run -it <container_id> dir`
2. Modify the dockerfile and add CMD at end of dockerfile - `CMD ["dir"]`, then run `docker run <container_id> dir`

How to list all directories and files inside docker?

Comment: Note that `docker run` needs the image name, not a container ID. The image being the thing that you've just built based off of the `Dockerfile`, and the container being the thing that you ran, instantiating the image, so to say.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use the `exec` command.

Now because you run a **windowsservercore based image** use `powershell` command (and not `/bin/bash` which you can see on many examples for linux based images and which is **not installed by default** on a windowsservercore based image) so just do:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> powershell
```

Now you should get an iteractive terminal and you can list your files with simply doing `ls` or `dir`

By the way, i found this question :

[Exploring Docker container's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system)

It contains a tons of answers and suggestions, maybe you could find other good solutions there (there is for example a very friendly CLI tool to exploring containers : https://github.com/wagoodman/dive)

Answer (score 8):

This is what I found helpful in the end.
Thanks to Nischay for leading the way.
The great thing about this, of course, is that one may examine the files even if the publish fails at a later stage.

```
# Copy everything...
COPY . ./
# See everything (in a linux container)...
RUN dir -s    
# OR See everything (in a windows container)...
RUN dir /s
```

Comment: `dir -s` will not work in all linux containers

Comment: for Unix-based containers it should be `ls` & related

Comment: I get no output with ls. It's just like it never runs the command or like it sends the output to /dev/null or whatever

Answer (score 4):

In your `Dockerfile` add the below command:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-windowsservercore
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN dir #Added
RUN pip download -r requirements.txt -d packages
```

Answer (score 2):

To list all of files and directories in side docker you can use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` command in front of the command to build the docker. For example: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t testApp .`
 **1.** inside the Dockerfile you can add `RUN ls` to your Dockerfile in which **ls** stand for **list**, it should be like this:

```
  FROM python:3.6.5-windowsservercore
  COPY . /app
  WORKDIR /app
  RUN pip download -r requirements.txt -d packages
  RUN ls
```

**2.** Then execute your Dockerfile with the command `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t any_of_your_docker_image_name .`

Let's me know if this address your expectation.