# Open an jpg image in a docker container

Tags: docker, image, containers, jpeg

I am trying to install a yolov project (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git) on a Nvidia jetson txt 2 (Ubuntu). Since I do not have all the permissions on Nvidia, I created a docker container so I can install all the dependencies that I want in my container. Everything works up to this step. I successfully run the yolov project in my container and the final step is to open an jpg image. But actually I dont know how to display an image from a container using command line terminal ? I already tried with imagemagick but nothing works. Is there a very simple way to do it ?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: So you have a Ubuntu-based (?) container with a JPEG image within it running on an unspecified host?

Comment: Do you actually have ImageMagick in Docker?  How do you know?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the host is the Nvidia JETSON device. Actually my question is more about this : the yolov application, running within my docker container, actually tries to get the images from the camera (connected to my Nvidia device via USB port), thus how can I make the container get this images from the OS so the container can forward these images to the yolov application running within the container ?

Comment: @fmw42 I installed it using "apt install imagemagick"

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand. Do you mean a single JPEG image or a video stream? Is the image being produced in the container or by some device attached to the Jetson's USB?

Answer (score 0):

Despite that it's been a long time since this has been asked, I think that one approach to solve this is to use the `docker cp` command.

Let's suppose that your container's name is `yolov`. If you execute

`docker cp yolov:/path/to/images /tmp/images/`

you can open the images in your local file system as you would do it with any other picture. Not the perfecto solution, but it should work.

This has been originally suggested in another post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42368711/2705572

Answer (score -2):

i hope my searches about your question would help!!
many article talking about inspect image in docker,

like this one about How to Create a Docker Image From a Container??
https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/create-docker-image/

and about looking into docker docs we found this
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/
so i hope this would help you!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).