# NextJS Docker error: Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

### Goal

Dockerize NextJS application

---

### Problem

`Docker compose up` yields in the following error: Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root.

---

### Application

**Files & folders**

```
docker-compose.yml
web
   .next
   pages
   public
   .dockerignore
   dockerfile
   [more nextjs files & folders here]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: web
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: rughood_web
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /web

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**.dockerignore**

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
node_modules
npm-debug.log
README.md
.git
```

---

### Note!

The NextJS application itself is working fine when I run `npm run dev` within the `web` directory (which invokes the script `"dev": "next dev"` in package.json). I only have the error when trying to dockerize it. Moreover, in the docker-compose I also initiate a Redis cache, which is working fine too. Therefore I conclude the error must be how I try to combine Docker and NextJS. Thank you very much in advance :)

---

### Update 1

**How I got there**
Using the tips from @HansKilian and [Exploring Docker container's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system) I did the following:

1. Cd to the `web` directory
2. Built an image from the dockerfile `docker build .`
3. Explored the image with the following command `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash name-of-image`
4. Once inside, execute `ls` or `ls -lsa`
   This gave me the following results:

**What's in the derived image**

```
dockerfile
next-env.d.ts
next.config.js
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
pages
public
tsconfig.json
[Among other files/folders]
```

So the pages folder actually seems to be in the root of the container, yet still I get the error (`pages` is a directory in the container in which I can `cd` and `-ls`)
P.s. don't forget to delete your image if you're not going to using it anymore

---

### Update 2

Building the image and running it from within the `web` directory actually works, so it might actually have something to do with the docker-compose?

Comment: I tried setting up a project like yours and used your docker-compose.yaml and dockerfile and it works like it should. Maybe try adding `RUN ls -lR` after `COPY . .` to check that everything looks like it should.

Comment: Thank you @HansKilian for taking the time! I found out what's in the container, so I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was trying every single line of code ever uploaded to the internet, I came back to my initial set-up (from the question) and suddenly it now does work. Source control confirming I didn't change a thing.

To be sure, I deleted all containers, images and volumes from Docker and ran `docker compose up`. Yet still it worked. Tried many things to recreated the error, but I couldn't. Thank you all for helping and hopefully this may be come to use for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working Dockerfile with nextjs:

```
FROM node:16.14.0

RUN npm install -g npm@8.5.5

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app

RUN npm i

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  project-name:
    image: project-name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: project-name
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```