# Max File Size (php.ini) for Docker on Mac - Magento (markoshust)

Tags: git, docker, github, phpstorm, magento2

I'm working with https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento and trying to import a large mysql db sqldump - about 207MB. I need to modify the php.ini for max_file_size, but apparently, Docker "hides" these settings.

If this is not possible, how do I change the max_file_size so I can import sqldump's this large?

I'm on Docker on a MacBook Pro/M2 Max.

Thanks.

Comment: Why "hides"? Maybe that setting is in another position

Comment: Everything I can find is that Docker masks these settings in the way that it handles this virtual container. But there must be some way to handle the equivalent to the max_file_size setting that is normally in a php.ini file. The big question is how I change that setting so I can import a larger sqldump.....

Comment: php.ini is included in that images, why can't you find it?

Comment: I'm not seeing it - can you give me a normal/default path? I can see my normal Mac php.ini, but not the one that Docker is using....

Comment: Could it be that you don't know how to enter a container?  Files aren't visible outside, unless there are some volumes mounted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system?rq=2

Comment: Thanks - I'm working on this. The containers are running, but some of the commands aren't working - so clearly, I have some work ahead of me to learn more.....

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I worked through this and used the docker exec -it command to look into the docker container. The /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini file (of course) 644 rights, and I don't have the su right to change since this is a docker-owned container. Next challenge, so I can change the max_file_size to 300M is figuring out how to get access rights to change the php.ini file. Any ideas?